# How to delete Facebook conversation on both sides?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I know a lot of people answer this with "well, you should have thought about that before pressing send" and I agree. But the person was at a time a very close friend whom I thought I can trust. That friendship is over and I have recently found out that some out of context screenshots are being shared by that person and I want that to stop.
So, is there any way to delete every single message I ever exchanged with that person? (Both on Facebook and Instagram). I am willing to sacrifice my profiles if that would make them disappear. I mean, if deleting both those accounts would get them to disappear, I'll do it. I'm honestly so tired of having someone use stuff said confidentially and taken out of context to ruin my life. So, does deleting the entire profile make conversations disappear and if it doesn't, is there anything I can do?

TL;DR: An ex-friend is sharing our private conversations with other people, I want to delete them somehow.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, there is [no way to do so.](https://www.facebook.com/help/192631610782421/) You can only still delete messages that are sent in the last 10 minutes on both sides. [Source](https://www.facebook.com/help/messenger-app/194400311449172)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to look up Facebook's Sharing Policy in depth. If your info is private and confidential, and is being misused by the said person by being quoted out of context, this action might violate Facebook's Community Standards.
You should approach them and if you can convince them of the merits of your case , they will take down the entire stuff.

Other than that, just by yourself , sadly you have no recourse, as the other  answer already points out - you have a 10-minute time limit to delete anything that you send,  from the other side's inbox ( Even this feature is a relatively new addition, having been launched in 2019).